# Unable to run check condition with ng-if in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check one condition here is how it looks like

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="EventList in EventLists" ng-if="EventList.start.dateTime | DateMonth == TodayDetail">
```

I am unable to perform this `ng-if="EventList.start.dateTime | DateMonth == TodayDetail"`

The date should be compare in this format "Jun 16" == "Jun 16" but it seems like there is this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '==' is an unexpected token at column 38 of the expression [EventList.start.dateTime | DateMonth == TodayDetail] starting at [== TodayDetail].
```

Anyone had face the same issue? Or know how can i solve this?

I just want to get the EventList of today date.

Comment: You can check similar [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240831/bitwise-operation-inside-angular-ng-if

Comment: @user3201500  try   (EventList.start.dateTime | DateMonth) == TodayDetail

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a filter the way that you're attempting here.
you can create a function in the controller's scope, that will offer this functionality.

Comment: Can you please provide any example of this?